# Order Lua Table in Descending Order (Highest to Lowest)

Tags: lua, lua-table

I've tried everything to try to get this lua table to order from highest to lowest. I've looked at other stackoverflow threads, all across the web, and it's not working.

```
local DTable = {}
local SC = 0
for e,q in pairs(LastATP) do
  local CT = {e,q}
  SC = SC + 1
  table.insert(DTable, SC, CT)
end         

table.sort(DTable, function(a, b) return a[2] < b[2] end)
```

"E" is a random key, ex) dxh3qw89fh39fh - whilst q is a number. Please help. I've tried everything. When I try to iterate through the sorted table I also use "for i,v in ipairs(DTable)" - Responses soon, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table.sort`'s comparator acts like `<` -- it uses it to arrange the values in the list so that the smallest is first and the largest is last. This looks like

> first < second < third < .... < last

If you want to reverse that order, you should give it a "`>` operation" instead:

> first > second > third > .... > last

```
-- Sort `DTable` by the second value in the pair, decreasing
table.sort(DTable, function(a, b) return a[2] > b[2] end)
```

---

In your question, you said the values like `q` were numbers. If they are in fact strings but you want to sort them as numbers, you should use `tonumber` to convert them:

```
-- Note that keeping track of "SC" is not necessary, it is just the
-- length of DTable, which is where table.insert inserts by default
table.insert(DTable, {e, tonumber(q)}))
```

Comment: That did not solve my issue, it only made it worse. Hmm. It's almost like table.sort() isn't making any difference at all.

Comment: I and the other readers of this question has very little context of what this script is supposed to be accomplishing and what the things are that are being fed into it. If you share code that we can *run*, then it's easier to help.

Comment: It's suppose to sort a table, setup like: `{["key"] = ["points"]}` and turn it into a, `{["num"] = {"key", "points"}}`, and then sort said table for a leaderboard displaying scores of highest to lowest. @Curtis F

Comment: @RyanHuellen - Try `local CT = {e,tonumber(q)}`

Comment: When I did that, "q" returned nil. So I figured there must be some sort of string mixed up in there, and sure enough - it was points,(other-stored-value), and I had to create a simple Split() function. Thanks for your help, @EgorSkriptunoff - If you post an answer stating to check your value with tonumber(q), I will mark it as an answer.